custom_labels for Google scraper
I need to implement custom_label_0 to custom_label_5 on my website to let Google scrape it and show in the Google Merchant center.
Currently I have it in place on the website for Meta -Facebook in this format:
<meta property="product:custom_label_0" content="xxx">

It works for Meta but Google doesn't recognise this format and I have not found anywhere how to properly set it for Google algorithm.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Automatic feeds do not support the meta tag containing the custom_label. This field will only work in a product feed file added to the Google Merchant Center account.
